# Is it possible to make generic work in AIDL

Tags: android, ipc, aidl

I have the following AIDL file

```
package com.mindtherobot.samples.tweetservice;

interface TweetCollectorListener {

  void handleTweetsUpdated();
}
```

I tried to make generic works in AIDL so far. It doesn't work. The following code will flag error.

```
package com.mindtherobot.samples.tweetservice;

interface TweetCollectorListener<E> {

  E handleTweetsUpdated();
}
```

It seems that generic doesn't work in AIDL. However, that's my guess, as [Android Interface Definition Language](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) doesn't talk much on generic.

Just want to confirm, is it true generic doesn't work in AIDL? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From The [official AIDL docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) :

> List
>
> All elements in the List must be one of the supported data types
>   in this list or one of the other AIDL-generated interfaces or
>   parcelables you've declared. A List may optionally be used as a
>   "generic" class (for example, List). The actual concrete class
>   that the other side receives is always an ArrayList, although the
>   method is generated to use the List interface. Map All elements in the
>
> Map
>
> must be one of the supported data types in this list or one of the
>   other AIDL-generated interfaces or parcelables you've declared.
>   Generic maps, (such as those of the form Map are not
>   supported. The actual concrete class that the other side receives is
>   always a HashMap, although the method is generated to use the Map
>   interface.

So, as you can see there is only limited support for generics using Lists, not even Maps, so no a custom parametrized types is not supported.